# (When) Is it necessary to call SHA1Managed.Initialize()?

Tags: c#

What does `SHA1Managed.Initialize()` actually do? When is it necessary to call it? [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1managed.initialize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is very sparse.

Comment: Looks like it just zeroes the internal buffer in case the memory region contains sensitive data: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/sha1managed.cs,e228b8e0c77ca9b1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

checking the decompiled code, It just clears out the `buffer` and `expandedBuffer` byte arrays:

```
public override void Initialize()
{
  this.InitializeState();
  Array.Clear((Array) this._buffer, 0, this._buffer.Length);
  Array.Clear((Array) this._expandedBuffer, 0, this._expandedBuffer.Length);
}
```

For conciseness, the `InitializeState` method, which is also called in the constructor:

```
private void InitializeState()
{
  this._count = 0L;
  this._stateSHA1[0] = 1732584193U;
  this._stateSHA1[1] = 4023233417U;
  this._stateSHA1[2] = 2562383102U;
  this._stateSHA1[3] = 271733878U;
  this._stateSHA1[4] = 3285377520U;
}
```

No need to call `Initialize` on construction.  Looks like more of a reset button.

Answer (score 0):

From the CoreCLR:

```
 [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    public override void Initialize() {
        if (_safeHashHandle != null && !_safeHashHandle.IsClosed)
            _safeHashHandle.Dispose();

        // _CreateHash will check for failures and throw the appropriate exception
        _safeHashHandle = Utils.CreateHash(Utils.StaticProvHandle, Constants.CALG_SHA1);
    }
```

It looks to be called as a part of standard implementations of HashAlgorihthm methods, and doesn't look like it ever needs to be called directly during normal usage.